# Is wkhtmltopdf and old Google Charts not working together anymore?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, pageload

I am tring to convert html with google charts to pdf format using wkhtmltopdf.
Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["piechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Symbol', 'Num of actions'],
      
      ['Tech',50],['Fund',50]

    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div_a'));
    chart.draw(data, {width: 200, height: 240, is3D: false, title: 'monthly Activity by Model Type', legend: 'bottom' ,colors: ['#33CCCC','#29A3A3'],backgroundColor:{fill:'transparent', stroke:'transparent',strokeWidth:2}});
    
      }
</script>
```

It worked fine until it stopped.

Now the pdf file is missing the charts. I did not change anything, May it be an issue of a version?

i tried to add  `window.status = 'ready_to_print';` at the end of drawChart()
and execute command with  --window-status ready_to_print.
Now the wkhtmltopdf waits for a long time and nothing happens.
Any Ideas?
Thank you very much.

(I also tried --javascript-delay)

UPDATE: when I ask "https://www.google.com/jsapi" I redirected to new one: "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"

this new version of api does not work with wkhtmltopdf,
Is there any way to work with old version?

Thanks again

Comment: did you manage to solve the issue?